# Como trabalhar com github quando A2F está habilitada?

Tags: git, github

Ao habilitar a autenticação de dois fatores no Github sou obrigado a trabalhar com chave RSA para atualizar os repositórios?

Quando A2F (*Authentication Two-Factor*) está ativa o código único é solicitado, imagino que o Git em si não trabalha com isso, logo, acredito que, neste cenário sou obrigado a usar uma chave de autenticação, tipo RSA. Estou correto?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não é obrigado.

Usando "A2F" (ou 2FA ou *Two-factor Authentication*), [você pode trabalhar](https://help.github.com/articles/accessing-github-using-two-factor-authentication/#authenticating-on-the-command-line-using-https) usando a chave RSA (chave SSH) ou via HTTPS.

Se quer usar HTTPS, você precisa criar um token de acesso pessoal **que será usado como senha** quando for autenticar via linha de comando usando uma URL https. Desta forma, o uso do token fica transparente mesmo que o Git em si não trabalhe com isto.

Comment: Bacana, essa do token eu não sabia. Obrigado!